# Mapping XMLs with different schemas to the same classes using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have these two types of XMLs with no predefined schemas:

## A

```
<root-a>
  <a-item id="a1">
    <name>Name of A1</name>
    <a-item id="a11">
      <name>Name of A11</name>
    </a-item>
    <a-item id="a12">
      <name>Name of A12</name>
      <a-item id="a121">
        <name>Name of A121</name>
      </a-item>
      <a-item id="a122">
        <name>Name of A122</name>
      </a-item>
    </a-item>
  </a-item>
  <a-item id="a2">
    <name>Name of A2</name>
  </a-item>
</root-a>
```

## B

```
<root-b>
  <b-item id="b1">
    <name>Name of B1</name>
    <b-item id="b11">
      <name>Name of B11</name>
    </b-item>
    <!-- etc., similar to A -->
  </b-item>
</root-b>
```

The items can be nested to an arbitrary depth. The structure is the same, but the name of the root element and of the item elements is different. How can I map it to a single Java class structure, eg. like this one (getters and setters omitted) using JAXB:

```
public class Root {
  private List<Item> items;
}

public class Item {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private List<Item> items;
}
```

I can map just one of the XML structures using JAXB annotations, but I don't know how to do it to accommodate both XMLs at the same time. I could create a parallel hierarchy for A and B with a common interface, but I hope there's a neater solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is XML schema based on your description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <!-- Root elements -->
    <xs:element name="root-a" type="rootAType"/>
    <xs:element name="root-b" type="rootBType"/>

    <!-- root-a type -->
    <xs:complexType name="rootAType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="a-item" type="itemAType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- root-b type -->
    <xs:complexType name="rootBType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="b-item" type="itemBType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- abstract item type -->
    <xs:complexType name="itemType" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- item-a type -->
    <xs:complexType name="itemAType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="itemType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="a-item" type="itemAType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- item-b type -->
    <xs:complexType name="itemBType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="itemType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="b-item" type="itemBType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

On base of this schema following classes were created:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "itemType", propOrder = {
    "name"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ItemAType.class,
    ItemBType.class
})
public abstract class ItemType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    protected String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "itemAType", propOrder = {
    "aItem"
})
public class ItemAType
    extends ItemType
{

    @XmlElement(name = "a-item")
    protected List<ItemAType> aItem;

    public List<ItemAType> getAItem() {
        if (aItem == null) {
            aItem = new ArrayList<ItemAType>();
        }
        return this.aItem;
    }

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "itemBType", propOrder = {
    "bItem"
})
public class ItemBType
    extends ItemType
{

    @XmlElement(name = "b-item")
    protected List<ItemBType> bItem;

    public List<ItemBType> getBItem() {
        if (bItem == null) {
            bItem = new ArrayList<ItemBType>();
        }
        return this.bItem;
    }

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "rootAType", propOrder = {
    "aItem"
})
public class RootAType {

    @XmlElement(name = "a-item")
    protected List<ItemAType> aItem;

    public List<ItemAType> getAItem() {
        if (aItem == null) {
            aItem = new ArrayList<ItemAType>();
        }
        return this.aItem;
    }

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "rootBType", propOrder = {
    "bItem"
})
public class RootBType {

    @XmlElement(name = "b-item")
    protected List<ItemBType> bItem;

    public List<ItemBType> getBItem() {
        if (bItem == null) {
            bItem = new ArrayList<ItemBType>();
        }
        return this.bItem;
    }

}
```

That seems to be a bit too complicated, but if you have more common functionality between a-item and b-item, the structure will become more convenient.